# Is there a way to speed up this nested for loop? (Multithreading?)

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, for-loop

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to speed up a nested for loop that's currently taking approximately 8 hours to run.

Clarification on what the code is trying to do:

*- Loop through two lists and filter another DataFrame based on the items of the items from these lists. Then I filter a second DataFrame based on these values and aggregate a column on it. Finally, I write the result with the filter items and the aggregated value to another DataFrame.*

- The code loops through a date list (1000 days), and a series of objects.
- Then it filters another large DataFrame (500,000 rows) based on those objects and aggregates a column as a sum.
- Lastly it takes the previous object values, the date from the loop and the aggregated value and it appends to a new DataFrame.

  ```
  #Create Date List ascending per day
  base = datetime.datetime.today()
  numdays = 1000
  dateList = [(base - datetime.timedelta(days=x)).date() for x in range(numdays)]
  dateList.reverse()

  #Initialize empty objects
  data = pd.DataFrame([])


  for date in dateList: 
      for asset in assetList:
          dfi = df.copy()
          dfi = dfi[dfi['AssetNum'] == asset]
          dfi = dfi[dfi['InstallDate']<date]
          dfi = dfi.reset_index(drop=True)

          try:
              installDate= dfi['InstallDate'].loc[0]

              sti = st.copy()
              sti = sti[sti['ASSETSERIAL'] == asset]
              sti = sti[sti['TIMESTAMP']>installDate]
              sti = sti[sti['TIMESTAMP']<date]

              cycles= sti['CYCLES'].sum()

              data = data.append(pd.DataFrame({'AssetNumber': asset, 'InstallDate': installDate,  'CurrentDate':date, 'Cycles':cycles}, index=[0]), ignore_index=True)


           except:
               pass
  ```

Lastly here's a quick glance at how the DataFrames look:

***df*** (4000 rows)

```
     AssetNum      InstallDate
     SRF63712      2019-04-12
     SRF39304      2020-11-28
     SRF15302      2019-06-23
        ...           ...
```

***st*** (500k rows)

```
      ASSETSERIAL     TIMESTAMP      CYCLES
       SRF63712       2020-01-01      354
       SRF39304       2020-01-01      163
       SRF15302       2020-01-01      356
       SRF63712       2020-01-01       35
       SRF39304       2020-01-01      253
       SRF15302       2020-01-01      352
       SRF63712       2020-01-01       43
       SRF39304       2020-01-01      566
       SRF15302       2020-01-01      231
```

Thanks to everyone in advance!

The loop keeps adding "CYCLES" to each Asset until it reaches a new InstallDate, and appends the result to the DataFrame.

Comment: What exactly are you doing? It might be better to explain what data you have and what you're trying to find out from it, because I cannot figure it out from the code you've written.

Comment: You are looping over `assetList` but only the last value is used, all the other calculations are discarded. Are you sure about the indentation of your `try` block?

Comment: I've made a few updates to the problem statement above. Simply put, what I'm trying to do is speed up the for loop. I'm not sure if there's a generic way to speed up any for loop by multiprocessing or some similar method?